# How to remove a component from an array in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

How can I remove an item from the `data` when clicking the div inside Item?

```
var App = React.createClass({
  ...
  handleSubmit: function(e) {
    this.state.data.push({ x: this.state.x });
  }
});
```

The item's class to remove.

```
var Item = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      return (
        <li>
          <div onClick={this.removeItem}></div>
        </li>
      )
    }
});
```

The list class.

```
var ItemList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var items = this.props.data.map(function(item) {
      return <Item x={item.x}>
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `App` component manages the `data` array, you need to bubble the remove request all the way from `Item` to `ItemList` to `App`.

So pass a callback from `App` to `ItemList`:

```
var App = React.createClass({
  ...
  removeItem: function(index) {
    this.setState(function(state) {
      var newData = state.data.slice();
      newData.splice(index, 1);
      return {data: newData};
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      ... <ItemList onRemove={this.removeItem} /> ...
    );
  },
  ...
});
```

And pass that callback into each `Item`:

```
var ItemList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var items = this.props.data.map(function(item, index) {
      return <Item x={item.x} index={index} onRemove={this.props.onRemove}>
    }.bind(this));
    ...
  }
});
```

Finally, call `onRemove` from `Item`:

```
var Item = React.createClass({
  ...
  removeItem: function() {
    this.props.onRemove(this.props.index);
  },
});
```

Comment: In your answer, shouldn't 'removeItem' be 'onRemove'?

Comment: And why are you using 'this.props.x' as a parameter to onRemove

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I found a few errors just after posting. I think I have caught most of them now, but let me know if I missed anything. :)

Comment: Why do you have bind(this)?

Comment: I refer to `this.props` inside the callback, and the callback isn't guaranteed to have the same `this` unless you bind it.

Comment: It's missing "this.removeItem.bind(this)". Without "bind(this)", it won't have access to App's state data.